# Fourier Series and differential equation with epsilon

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, fourier-series, approximation, nonlinear-system

Happy New Year!

I am stuck for days on expressing the solution of a differential equation using Fourier series.

The question is:

> Consider the equation:
>   $$\ddot{x}+x+\epsilon\left(\alpha x^2\text{sgn}(x)+\beta x^3\right)=0,\ 0<\epsilon \ll1,\ \alpha>0,\ \beta>0$$
>   where $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants
>
> With initial condition $x(0)=0$,
>   show that solution with angular frequency $w$ can be expresed as Fourier series:
>   $$x(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}B_{2k-1}\sin\left((2k-1)wt\right)=B_1\sin(wt)+B_3\sin(3wt)+...$$
>
> Assuming $w$ and $B_n$ can be expanded as power series in $\epsilon$,
>   show that as $\epsilon\to0$, $w=1+O(\epsilon)$, $B_1=O(1)$, $B_n=O(\epsilon)$ for $n=3,5,7,...$

Appreciate for some lights!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cheers, I managed to solve it.

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: King, the picture is embedded in stack exchange. Will have to get used to type equations on the website. :)

Comment: My mistake,sry for that.